# Acoustic echo cancellation in C# client

Tags: c#, server, client, echo-cancellation

I have a dispatcher's desk (client) and radio state (server) with speakers and microphones. These communicate with RTP protocol. They send and recieve data and play their immediately. My problem is that speakers must be loud. Therefore, echo is annoying. I did not found usefull AEC program for C#. So, I appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies of webRTC are huge and complex. It is unnecessary, if you only want to use AEC package. Therefore, I searched another solution and I have found Speex open source project. It is C++ code, but you can use with wrapper project (CLI/C++) in C# project.

Comment: Have you able to use speex for your project? I am scratching my head atm because there is no aec functions again in libspeexdsp

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not package that is ready for C# but you can build a wrapper in C# for any AEC package you can find. I think there are two main options for AEC package: 1. Open source packages - like the AEC component of webRTC (https://webrtc.org/) 2. Commercial package like SoliCall (http://solicall.com).

A third option you might want to consider is doing the echo cancellation on the network. Assuming you are using SIP/RTP - take a look at the PBXMate product.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yep, My opinion is very similar. I probably use a wrapper.

Comment: Have you found solution for this? I am scratching my head, as I can't find AEC functions in speex, in which speex urge us to use opus, while opus encourage us to us webRTC and .. how?